# How to use the same element into a function which triggers the onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following coding for the script in external file

```
function DiableLink(elem){
   console.log($(elem).attr('type'));
   if($(elem).hasClass('disabled')) {
       return false;
   }
   else {
       $(elem).addClass('disabled');
   }
}
```

Used as follow in the html

```
<a onClick="DiableLink(this);" class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"></a>
```

I used the same function using ID as follow

```
$(function(){
   $('.hid').click(function(){
      var link = $(this);
      if(link.hasClass('disabled')) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         link.addClass('disabled');
      }
  }); 
});
```

which is perfectly working (I got it from the stackoverflow).
But i don't know why calling in onclick event doesn't work. Please can anyone help? where i got wrong

Comment: did you put the function b/w `<script></script>` tag??

Comment: Do i need to put in a external JavaScript file?? becasue without it the code i mention last worked@ozil

Comment: you can put the function in same file having `<a onClick="DiableLink(this);" class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"></a>` tag. but place it in `<script></script>` tag

Comment: but i need to call this function in other files also (re-usability), i prefer it in a external file. Is only works if i put in the same file? @ozil

Comment: yes you can put it `external js file` don't forget to include the reference of that file :P

Comment: Ya i tested i am referring it correctly :)

Comment: Try wrapping it in `head`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `onclick=""` atrribute empty if you are using a event handler instead of a function.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/1wr7wdyt/)**

Comment: I am asking solution for the first code i post not the last code, which is working and i didn't use the onclick while using that code :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Your solution actually works with [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tudicotafa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

I wrote:

> I'd call the function inside href:
>
> ```
> <a href="javascript: yourFunction(); location.href='newpage.js';">Click</a>
> ```

But it wouldn't work if you want to pass the anchor tag element through href attribute. So this will **NOT** work:

```
<a href="javascript: yourFunction(this); location.href='newpage.js';">Click</a>
```

In this case you have to use the onclick event (inline or in a separate file, as I wrote before).

Comment: Downvoted your answer because you should at least have researched whether or not `onClick` is case sensitive. Answers with direct assumptions are hard to take seriously. Just something to keep in mind. :)

Comment: Soon after submitting the answer I researched it :) Anyway you're right, I should have done it before.

Comment: Edit your answer and I'll remove the downvote, fair and square!

Comment: Nope, It also not working :(
@insane.user17 when i use like this don't i need to mention the function as `Diablelink(this)`

Comment: If it is disabled then next time i click i won't able to visit the site, that is the actual disabling... i think :) @insane.user17