# OnClick function issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using following coding in a external js file

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
var elem='<img class="imgload" src="/common/images/spinLoader/transperent.png">'; 
$('.imgchange').append(elem);

});

$(function(){
    $('.hid').click(function(){
    $('.imgload').attr('src',"/common/images/spinLoader/loader_icon.gif"); 
    var link = $(this);
    if(link.hasClass('disabled'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        link.addClass('disabled');
    }
     });
});
```

In the HTML

```
<td><a class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"></a></td><td class="imgchange"></td>
```

The whole set up is to disable the link and display spinning loading icon after user clicks the link.

The problem is i firefox 38.0.1 the link is disabled but the image doesn't change to loading icon at first click. **IF i click another time only the image is changing.**
I checked with the debugger, when i run through the debugger the image is changing at the first click.
I tried putting the `onclick` function inside the `$( document ).ready()` it doesn't worked.
**FYI:** It is working without problem in **Chrome Version - 43.0.2357.65 m** and **IE 11**.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML element is not correctly formatted, the "" should move inside the "" scope, and the "" should be "", maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain

Comment: <td><a class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"><td></a><td class="imgchange"></td> should be <td><a class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"></a></td><td class="imgchange"></td>

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, i wrote wrong in the question. i have changed it. In the source it's like what you mention

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue using:

firefox 38.0.1-1 (linux machine).

I got it working as you want to, So I don't know where is your problem comming. I can suggest a little change that maybe is causing the issue:

```
<td><a class="hid" href="somelink.jsp"></a></td><td class="imgchange"></td>
```

Removing the href, cause it makes no sense for me to use .click() function on element that has it owns function (HTML).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .imgchange{ width: 100px; height: auto; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td><a class="hid" onclick="myFunction('link2.html');">Click me!</a></td><td class="imgchange"></td></tr>
</table>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var elem = '<img class="imgload" src="http://m.mexicodesconocido.com.mx/images/lazy-thumb.gif">'; 
  $('.imgchange').append(elem);

});

function myFunction(link){
 $('.imgload').attr('src',"http://www.deckers.com/wp-content/plugins/simplemap/inc/images/loading.gif");
 if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
 {
 return false;
 }
 else
 {
 $(this).addClass('disabled');
 }
 location.href = link;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7 64 bit. And what you suggest won't help me in my situation. Because the function have to be able to use in different locations, where the link will be different

Comment: I couldn't find any solution, so i leave it before my head get explode :)

Comment: What about an html element with onclick="function('link.jsp');" so you do all the stuff in that function. I will code it when I get home.

Comment: I tried it to put in a function but it doesn't succeeded that's why i change to use classes.  related question for the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122832/how-to-use-the-same-element-into-a-function-which-triggers-the-onclick-event

Comment: I updated my code in the answer, It's working in Windows 7 64 bits: Firefox 38.0.1.

Comment: OK, thanks for your effect. i have no idea what causing it, may be the error occurs in my environment only :(